# Homology of a boundary in ambient manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $M$ be a compact oriented $m$-dimensional manifold with a boundary $N \neq \emptyset$. Then $N$ is a closed oriented $m-1$-dimensional manifold.

Is it always true that the homology class $[N]_M$ has to vanish in $H_{m-1}(M, \mathbb Z)$?

Comment: Let $M$ be a compact connected orienteted $n$-manifold with non-empty boundary $\partial M$. Let $N_1,..., N_k$  be connected components of $\partial M$, and using induced orientation on $\partial M$, let $[N_1],...,[N_k]$ be the generators of $H_{n-1}(N_1;\Bbb Z),...,H_{n-1}(N_k;\Bbb Z)$, respectively. Then homology long exact sequence for the pair gives

Comment: $$\cdots \to \underset{\cong 0}{\underbrace{H_n(M;\Bbb Z)}}\to \underset{\cong \Bbb Z}{\underbrace{H_n(M,\partial M;\Bbb Z)}}\xrightarrow{1\longmapsto (1,...,1)} \underset{\cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^k\Bbb Z}{\underbrace{H_{n-1}(\partial M;\Bbb Z)=\bigoplus_{i=1}^kH_{n-1}(N_i;\Bbb Z)}}\to H_{n-1}(M;\Bbb Z)\to \cdots$$

Comment: That is the generator $[M]$ of $H_n(M,\partial M;\Bbb Z)$ goes to the element $[\partial M]:=\bigoplus_{i=1}^k [N_i]$ of $H_{n-1}(\partial M;\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: You should elaborate your comments in an answer?

Answer (score 3):

If $M$ is a compact oriented $m$-dimensional manifold with non-empty boundary $N$, then the image of the fundamental class of $[N]$ with respect to the natural inclusion $i(n)=n$ lives in $H_{m-1}(M)$, not in top homology of $M$ (you wrote $n$ but I assume you meant to write $m$). I think it is true that the image will always be zero, since it is a boundary. If you assume that everything is smooth and you work with real coefficients, then the image will be zero by Stokes theorem. More concretely, if you have a closed $m-1$ form $\omega$, then $\int_N \omega = \int_{\partial M} \omega = \int_M d\omega=0$, hence the image of $[N]$ is zero.

Comment: I meant $n$ as $m-1$, now I edited OP.

Comment: There is no smoothness assumption in the OP.

Comment: Well, thats why I wrote “I think this is true”. After that I showed it is true in smooth case with real coeff. You can still answer the general case. :)

Comment: @Laci It's already answered by User in comments.

Comment: He showed, that the generator of  $H_n(M,\partial M, \mathbb{Z})$ maps to the sum of generators in $\partial M$ but the question was about the image of the boundary in the homology of $M$.

Comment: As @Laci said, my question is different.